# Convert Strings inside Iterator to Python list

Tags: python, string, list

I have a start date and an end date and I want them to appear as string values inside a list.

**Example**

```
datebetween = `["2020-01-01" , "2020-01-02" , "2020-01-03" ... ]
```

...

I wrote the code below to form an iterator and to get the dates but how can I convert those dates to final as list :

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-02-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-03-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days+1)]

# print ("data gen" , date_generated)

for date in date_generated:
    var = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    print (var)
```

Showing as below :

```
2020-02-02
2020-02-03
2020-02-04
2020-02-05
2020-02-06
2020-02-07
2020-02-08
2020-02-09
2020-02-10
2020-02-11
2020-02-12
2020-02-13
2020-02-14
```

I want the final var to be like :   `["2020-02-02" , "2020-02-03" , "2020-02-04" .... ]`

Comment: Instead of your loop, what if you say: `[x.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") for x in date_generated]` If you want to have another list.  If you want to define it as another generator, use parens instead of brackets.

Comment: Patch your list comp with `(start + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d")`

Comment: works great . yes I was pretty close

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can format the dates inside the comprehension like:

```
date_generated = [(start + datetime.timedelta(days=x)).strftime("%Y-%m-%d") 
                  for x in range(0, (end-start).days+1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you can do to achieve this, simply add the dates to a list after converting them to string.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-02-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-03-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days+1)]

# print ("data gen" , date_generated)
var_list = list()
for date in date_generated:
    var = date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    var_list.append(var)
```

Output of var_list

```
['2020-02-02',
 '2020-02-03',
 '2020-02-04',
 '2020-02-05',
 '2020-02-06',
 '2020-02-07',
 '2020-02-08',
 '2020-02-09',
 '2020-02-10',
 '2020-02-11',
 '2020-02-12',
 '2020-02-13',
 '2020-02-14',
 '2020-02-15',
 '2020-02-16',
 '2020-02-17',
 '2020-02-18',
 '2020-02-19',
 '2020-02-20',
 '2020-02-21',
 '2020-02-22',
 '2020-02-23',
 '2020-02-24',
 '2020-02-25',
 '2020-02-26',
 '2020-02-27',
 '2020-02-28',
 '2020-02-29',
 '2020-03-01',
 '2020-03-02']
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a final list called

```
  storeFinalDates = []
```

and then in the for loop call and append the dates to it like this:

```
  storeFinalDates.append(str(var))
  print(storeFinalDates)
```

Hope that helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-02-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-03-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end- 
start).days+1)]

# print ("data gen" , date_generated)
datesList=[]
for date in date_generated:
    datesList.append(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
print (datesList)
```

Comment: how that is different than other reply ... ? If you want to get credit lets get in right way and not just copy paste

Answer (score 0):

I thought I'd add this to the list of solutions.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd

start = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-02-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
end = datetime.datetime.strptime("2020-03-02", "%Y-%m-%d")
date_generated = [start + datetime.timedelta(days=x) for x in range(0, (end-start).days+1)]

# print ("data gen" , date_generated)
result = []
for date in date_generated:
    result.append(str(date).split()[0])

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
['2020-02-02',
 '2020-02-03',
 '2020-02-04',
 '2020-02-05',
 '2020-02-06',
 '2020-02-07',
 '2020-02-08',
 '2020-02-09',
 '2020-02-10',
 '2020-02-11',
 '2020-02-12',
 '2020-02-13',
 '2020-02-14',
 '2020-02-15',
 '2020-02-16',
 '2020-02-17',
 '2020-02-18',
 '2020-02-19',
 '2020-02-20',
 '2020-02-21',
 '2020-02-22',
 '2020-02-23',
 '2020-02-24',
 '2020-02-25',
 '2020-02-26',
 '2020-02-27',
 '2020-02-28',
 '2020-02-29',
 '2020-03-01',
 '2020-03-02']
```

Comment: @pauldx - One line of code within the for loop and that I used `result.append(str(date).split()[0])` which I don't see any other solution used. It is a different answer. I think before accusing me of intentionally trying to do things the wrong way to get credit, you could analyze the solution I proposed and the difference with other solutions here.